# Как сделать замену кнопки при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: css, jquery, html5

Не знаю как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку меню, меню пропадала вместо меню появлялась на этом же месте кнопка закрыть при нажатии на кнопку закрыть появлялась меню сам код:

```
<div class="menu-mob">
 <button class="mob-menu"></button>
</div>

css

.mob-menu{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px 0px 17px 20px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    background-image: url(img/menu-mob.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Простой пример.**

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const open = document.querySelector('.menu__open');
const close = document.querySelector('.menu__close');

open.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.add('menu_open');
});

close.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.remove('menu_open');
});
```

```css
.menu__close {
  display: none;
}

.menu__container {
  display: none;
}

.menu_open .menu__close {
  display: block;
}

.menu_open .menu__open {
  display: none;
}

.menu_open .menu__container {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__open">Открыть меню</div>
  <div class="menu__close">Закрыть меню</div>

  <div class="menu__container">
    <p>Hello, world</p>
  </div>
</div>
```